# How to compare user input date with mongodb ISODate object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, isodate

I am new to MongoDB and I stuck at one point, following is the explanation.

I am getting a date in format dd-mm-yyyy and I want to find all the data according to the particular date which I am getting. 
But on the mongo side, I am having a field createdAt, which contains ISODate formatted values.
While comparing these two I am not getting any data.

```
mySchema.find({createdAt: {"$eq": date}}).exec();
```

Here createdAt value in the database is ISODate("2020-05-05T14:49:37.210Z") and we are getting a date as 05-05-2020

Please help me out to understand where I am doing wrong.

Comment: could you try this `mySchema.find({ createdAt: { "$eq": new Date(date) } }).exec();`?

Comment: @MohammedYousry I have tried that but it's not working, same it not giving any data.

Comment: new Date("05-05-2020") will return something like ISODate("2020-05-05T00:00:00.000Z), while the createdAt date is ISODate("2020-05-05T14:49:37.210Z"), so they are not identical, that's why you don't get any records matching this query

Comment: do you need to get all the records that have a createdDate 05-05-2020 regardless the time of that day?

Comment: @MohammedYousry exactly I need in that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the ISO date to any string format you wan in **aggregation pipeline** by **dateToString** function and then compare it.

Below is the example of how to create a schema and then use it code.

```
// UserModal.js

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var UserSchema = new Schema({
    first_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    last_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    ......
}, { timestamps: true });


//make this available to our users in Node applications
module.exports.User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Then in controller

```
const User = require("UserModal").User;

User.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "dateString": { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$createdAt" } }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      dateString: {
        $eq: "2020-05-05"
      }
    }
  }
]).exec((err, records) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(records);
})
```

Comment: thank you for your reply @Puneet Singh Ji. But I want to know where I can write this code, as I am having code in the model for schema and comparison code I am putting in the controller

Comment: @AbhishekRawal Included the schema in the answer as well, the timestamp option will automatically add the createdAt field in the records.